# `Modifier.composed` in the subnode of Pager uses rememberCoroutineScope, get left composition cancellation unexpected

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines

When I add a symbol to `Pager` (or more accurately, `HorizontalPager`) get an unexpected results when using a custom Modifier extension function. Here are the extensions I'm using.

```kotlin
fun Modifier.repeatable(
    tag: String = "",
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    delayMillis: Int? = null,
    onEnd: (() -> Unit)? = null,
    onRepeat: () -> Unit,
) = this.composed {
    val rememberedIsEnabled by rememberUpdatedState(enabled)
    val rememberedOnRepeat by rememberUpdatedState(onRepeat)
    val rememberedOnEnd by rememberUpdatedState(onEnd)
    
    val interaction = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
    val longPressTimeout = (delayMillis ?: ViewConfiguration.getLongPressTimeout()).milliseconds
    
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    
    scope.coroutineContext.job.invokeOnCompletion { cause ->
        Log.w(tag, "invokeOnCompletion: $cause")
    }
    
    Modifier
        .pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectTapGestures(onPress = { offset ->
                Log.w(tag, "detectTapGestures")
                if (rememberedIsEnabled) {
                    try {
                        val job = scope.launch {
                            Log.w(tag, "job launched")
                            var first = true
                            
                            try {
                                Log.w(tag, "delay: $longPressTimeout")
                                delay(longPressTimeout)
                                val repeatInterval = 100.milliseconds
                                
                                while (rememberedIsEnabled) {
                                    rememberedOnRepeat()
                                    
                                    first = false
                                    
                                    Log.w(tag, "count: $count, delay: $repeatInterval")
                                    delay(repeatInterval)
                                }
                            } finally {
                                withContext(NonCancellable) {
                                    Log.w(tag, "count: $count")
                                    if (first) rememberedOnRepeat()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        
                        Log.w(tag, "emit interaction")
                        val pressInteraction = PressInteraction.Press(offset)
                        interaction.emit(pressInteraction)
                        
                        val success = tryAwaitRelease()
                        
                        val endInteraction = if (success) PressInteraction.Release(pressInteraction)
                        else PressInteraction.Cancel(pressInteraction)
                        
                        interaction.emit(endInteraction)
                        
                        job.cancelAndJoin()
                    } finally {
                        rememberedOnEnd?.invoke()
                    }
                }
            })
        }
        .indication(interactionSource = interaction, indication = rememberRipple())
}
```

Many of these logs were added during debugging.
In a HorizontalPager with three pages, I added an Icon to each page and used the extension. However, after switching pages (e.g., from page 1 to page 2 and back to page 1), the extension does not work.

After adding Log, I tracked the following phenomenon:

1. When entering Pager, the function works, all logs shown.
2. When switching from page 1 to page 2, the function works in page 2, all logs shown.
3. When switching back to page 1, the function call fails, the Log only has "detectTapGesture" and "emit interaction", and the function is not working. In more detail, no ripple, and I find no "invokeOnCompletion", but when I debug, `scope.coroutineContext.job.isCancelled` is true.
4. Exit Pager (i.e. no longer visible), re-enter and the function works.

What is the problem?